# scraping historical stock prices in google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I want to scrape the historical prices for a specific from [this link](https://maya.tase.co.il/fund/5115167?view=history&q=%7B%22Period%22:8,%22DateFrom%22:%222021-01-30T22:00:00.000Z%22,%22DateTo%22:%222021-01-30T22:00:00.000Z%22,%22Page%22:1%7D) (154.94).
The stock ID (5115167) and the custom dates I will generate from other cells in the sheet for the URL.
I tried scraping with `=IMPORTXML(A1,...)` and `=IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",...)` but it's not working.
Tried the following XML:

```
//*[@id="printThisElement"]/div[2]
//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]
//*[@id="printThisElement"]/div[2]/div[3]
```

Neither of those are working.

Comment: This page is running ajax call.

Comment: So how should I approach this?